# sysdate and dbtimezone different in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, sysdate

With this query: `select sysdate from dual;`

the result is: `27-09-2018 07:50:50`  -- this `UK` time

with : `Select dbtimezone from dual;`

output: `+10:00`

I want the `sysdate` to be of the same timezone of `dbtimezone`

I was trying to do it with `alter database set time_zone='AEST'`, but i'm bit confused if this is the right solution.

Any help most appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It is a common misunderstanding that `DBTIMEZONE` is the time zone for `SYSDATE` and  `SYSTIMESTAMP`

`SYSDATE` and  `SYSTIMESTAMP` are returned in time zone of the operating system on which the database server resides.

`DBTIMEZONE` is the (internal) time zone of `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME` values. I don't know any practical use of it. Note, you cannot change `DBTIMEZONE` on your database if the database contains a table with a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column and the column contains data.

If you want current time at DBTIMEZONE run

```
select SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE 
from dual;
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE` is also working.

See also [How to handle Day Light Saving in Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926)

Comment: Ok..Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

[`SYSDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions207.htm) returns the current date and time set for the operating system on which the database server resides.

[`CURRENT_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions051.htm) returns the current date in the session time zone.

```
show parameter nls_date_format

NAME                           TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------
nls_date_format                string      dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss


select sysdate, current_date, dbtimezone from dual;

SYSDATE              CURRENT_DATE         DBTIME
-------------------- -------------------- ------
27-Sep-2018 08:16:00 27-Sep-2018 08:16:00 +00:00


alter session set time_zone = '+08:00';

Session altered.


select sysdate, current_date, dbtimezone from dual;

SYSDATE              CURRENT_DATE         DBTIME
-------------------- -------------------- ------
27-Sep-2018 08:13:06 27-Sep-2018 15:13:06 +00:00
```